# Python Telnet connection using socket library: How can I receive the entire response instead of just one character?

Tags: python, tcp

I have the following code in python to connect by TCP to a machine, send a command and expect the answer.

```
import socket

HOST = "MACHINE_IP_ADRESS"
PORT = "PORT_NUMBER"
COMMAND = "COMMAND_LINE"

# Connect to the server
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    print("Connected to {}:{}".format(HOST, PORT))

    # Send the command
    s.sendall(COMMAND.encode('utf-8'))
    print("Sent command: {}".format(COMMAND))

    # Receive and print the answer
    answer = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    print('Received answer:', repr(answer))
```

When I run the code I get the correct answer in a PuTTY terminal ">SERIAL NUMBER, XXXXXX" but just get the first character in the terminal where i run the python program.

Is there a way I can get python to print the complete response from server? I'm completely new to python and been surfing for a while without luck.

Thanks for your support

I tried with scket library and expected a string of characters but just received the first one.

Comment: You need to call `recv()` in a loop.

Comment: Why are you doing this with sockets instead of `telnetlib`?

Comment: You could keep calling recv until you find a `b"\n"` in the data stream. Now, everything up to that character can be split out and decoded.

Comment: It has nothing to do with python and your expectation is wrong. TCP isn’t message-based.  You have to follow the telnet protocol. Buffer receives and extract line-terminated responses